# Unable to run sample Android Wear app on physical device

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to figure out the Android Wear APIs. I've imported the [sample WatchFace app](https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/project.html) provided in the SDK. I've set up my phone *AND* Moto 360 physical watch for debugging. They both show up in adb devices, and I'm able to select both when running the application. I followed the [instructions from here.](http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html)

However, when I go to my phone (and check the android wear app) to find the watchfaces included in the sample app, they are nowhere to be found. If I check the watch, they are also nowhere to be found.

As a side issue, I had initially had Compatible = No, missing uses-feature watch, when trying to run on my 360. Notably, that permission was not in the manifest of the sample app, once I added it to the manifest, Compatible = Yes for the wearable module on my 360.

I am now going to try to make it work on the emulator to see if that's the issue.

Edit: Able to get it to work on emulator.

Comment: So did you succeed? Because it is working on emulator and you created separate question how to make it faster to deploy app to moto.

Comment: Yes I got it to work, I am not sure what I did to make it work though, which is why I haven't posted an answer. I believe I just restarted my computer, and re-forwarded the connection in ADB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten it to work, but I'm not sure what was the issue for it not working. If you are seeing this problem, this is what I would do to make sure you're setup properly:

1. Ensure your watch is paired with your phone in Android Wear.
2. Ensure both watch and phone have debugging enabled.
3. You can follow the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) for how to setup bluetooth debugging. Make sure that your device shows up when you run `adb devices`.
4. If you have both a Wearable module and Mobile module, make sure that if they are not set up to be launched via a launcher, that your run configurations are set to "Do not launch activity."
5. Run your Mobile module on your device first.
6. Then run your Wearable module on your wearable (it should show up as a device if you did everything right).
7. Your app should show up on both the watch and the device now. You can push changes to one or the other from now on (depending on which one you modified, or both if necessary). If you run into issues, just run the mobile module first and then wearable module.

Note that even though compatibility may say "No, missing feature WATCH" for your mobile device (e.g. phone) when you run your Mobile module, it should still work!

Comment: Please mark this as a right answer if it solved your problem.